# Anaconda Navigator not opening properly

Tags: anaconda

I entered anaconda-navigator and it showed this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(anaconda_navigator.app.main.main())
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 63, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 30, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 32, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/client_api.py", line 20, in <module>
    import binstar_client
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/binstar_client/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .errors import *
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/binstar_client/errors.py", line 1, in <module>
    from clyent.errors import ClyentError
  File "/Users/siddharthnayak/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/clyent/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

Can someone please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the command "anaconda-navigator --reset" in anaconda promt. Then you should be able to open the navigator with the command "anaconda-navigator".
It worked for me.